# How to correctly display umlauts in nodejs (electron)?

Tags: c#, node.js, dll, electron, diacritics

I have following function in my C#-Library which returns a xml string

```
[DllExport]
public static string ReadData(ushort port){
    ...
    return xmlString;
}
```

I have a tag containing the letter "ö" which is displayed like this `´┐¢` in Nodejs (Electron). When including the value in my html file and display it, there is just a question mark .I am not quite sure why. The encoding of the xml string ist `UTF-8`. When debugging the C#-function the xml string contains the correct letter but not in Nodejs.
I use the following code to include the DLL in order to call the function

```
const readDataLibrary = new ffi.Library(`${__dirname}/dll/MyDll`,{
  "ReadData": ["string", ["ushort"]]
})

// incorrect representation of umlauts
console.log(util.inspect(readDataLibrary.ReadData(8192), true,null, true))
```

I tried different approaches I found here on stack overflow like using the `TextDecoder/Encoder` but nothing seems to help.

EDIT: I found a workaround. I wrote a function which converts umlauts to specific characters so that I can reverse convert them in node.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that your string has the correct encoding, you can cast the string into a Buffer and then cast it back to a string, ensuring it has the UTF-8 encoding, like this:

```js
console.log(util.inspect(Buffer.from(readDataLibrary.ReadData(8192), 'utf-8').toString(), true, null, true))
```

Comment: I tried that too but it is not working neither.